# Disable Ember Mirage when running tests in the browser

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I would like to be able to run tests against my Mirage server, and my actual server in turn.

I've read [these docs](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/advanced/environment-options) on disabling Mirage, and it works as expected for the development environment. Adding the code below disables Mirage at http://localhost:4200.

```js
 ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
```

However, this does not disable mirage when running tests in the browser at http://localhost:4200/tests.

I have added the code above outside of any of the environment specific conditionals, so it should apply to all environments. For good measure, I have also tried adding the code above inside each of the three environment specific conditionals as well:

```js
 ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };

if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
}
if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
}
if (environment === 'test') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
}
```

http://localhost:4200/tests still uses Mirage.

Is there a way to disable Mirage when testing in the browser? I would like to be able to enable it easily, so uninstalling Mirage is not an option.

Comment: I'm quite surprised this isn't working. Just want to make sure you are stopping the server and restarting with `ember serve` again. The `environment.js` file doesn't get re-read until you restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

I had misunderstood the effect of adding `setupMirage(hooks);` in and acceptance test. ([docs here)](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/testing/acceptance-tests)

When it is present in your acceptance test, all requests will go to mirage, whether or not `ENV['ember-cli-mirage'].enabled` is true or false.

Conversely, when it is absent, all requests will be sent to your defined endpoint, whether or not `ENV['ember-cli-mirage'].enabled` is true or false.

This may explain why the [docs on enabling or disabling mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/advanced/environment-options) only refer to doing to for the `production` and `development` environments.

Comment: This is pretty confusing! The environment-specific config was from a time before setupMirage existed. Curious, what's your use case for disabling when running in the browser?

Comment: @SamSelikoff The user registration system of our app is very complicated, and there are a host of different UI configurations that a user could see, depending on what comes back from an auth request. Mirage is amazing for automatically testing that the correct UI shows for each case, but the mirage server setup is fairly intricate, and so we'd like to be able to test against our real server once in a while, to make sure the mirage server responses are not out of sync with the real server responses.

Comment: Out of interest, here is a gist of how I handle this in practice: https://gist.github.com/andrew-paterson/e895087fe67198e9d0b9eeadd7a20e9c

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Maybe restarting the server would help as @jrjohnson suggested. If that didn't work, configuring the `environment.js` file like so might help:

```js
module.exports = function(environment) {

  let ENV = {
    'ember-cli-mirage': {
      enabled: true,
      directory: 'mirage'
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV['ember-cli-mirage'].enabled = false;
  }

  return ENV;
};
```